# Populating 3 tabs with a single network call

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-tabs

Suppose I have 3 tabs each populated by separate fragments (containing a grid view). Lets say a single network call gives me the JSON data to populate all 3 tabs.

Assuming, there is no local database, how do I go about implementing this ? ie populating the 3 tabs from a single network call ?

I'm looking for the logic on how to implement this, rather than the code.

Thanks

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I have the model of each element in the gridview predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in a lot of ways here is one:

1) Create a network call on the main activity

2) When receiving the result send your result by [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to your fragments.(Note that your model must implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface so you can put the data to the intent)

3) In each fragment create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and in `onReceive` extract the data and update the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Will get back after trying this.

Comment: A small hiccup. Lets say I have 20 JSON objects received from the network call. Tab 1 needs to get 10 from it, Tab 2 six and Tab 3 rest four. Now, If I fire an Intent with 20 objects parceled into it, 

a) How does each fragment differentiate between the objects ?
b) If each fragment has to loop through the entire objects, would it be time consuming ?

Comment: I think it is not time consuming but you can split it and send 3 different broadcasts with different `intentfilter` for each fragment.